# Generate time series using spatial averaging by weight in xarray

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, python-xarray

I am trying to do spatial averaging over a region of interest to generate time series. but my data is missing at some point of time & space, that will directly affect the direct approach of lat-lon mean, as `xarray.mean(dim=['lat','lon']` do. So the appropriate way would be to account the proper weight while averaging. For example:-

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('dataset.nc')

SST = ds.vars_of_interest.sel(lat=slice(15,25), lon=slice(50,74))

time_series = np.asarray([])

for i in range(0,100):  # for 100 days of data
    latitudinal_mean   = SST[i].mean(dim='lat')   # do mean along latitude
    nonNaN_value_count = SST[i].count(dim='lat')  # count non-NaN values
    weighted_values    = latitudinal_mean*(nonNaN_value_count/nonNaN_value_count.sum())
    final_mean         = weighted_values.mean().values
    time_series        = np.append(time_series, np.round(final_mean,3))
```

is there any more direct or optimal way is to accomplish this task in xarray? Any comment from the community, thanks!

More about this approach has been discussed in a CDAT tutorial: [https://cdat.llnl.gov/Jupyter-notebooks/scientific/Detrend_Data/Detrend_Data.html#:~:text=Remove%20Climatological%20Mean%20Annual%20Cycle%20and%20Detrend%20Data&text=The%20analysis%20procedure%20involves%20three,mean%20and%20the%20linear%20trend.](https://cdat.llnl.gov/Jupyter-notebooks/scientific/Detrend_Data/Detrend_Data.html#:%7E:text=Remove%20Climatological%20Mean%20Annual%20Cycle%20and%20Detrend%20Data&text=The%20analysis%20procedure%20involves%20three,mean%20and%20the%20linear%20trend.)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.